# Run Terminal or Script on Startup in NetBeans

Tags: shell, ubuntu, netbeans, startup, autostart

I want netbeans to automatically opens terminal, 
maybe run some shell script, watch some files with Compass.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a duplicate of: [Run terminal command on startup of netbeans in mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272920/run-terminal-command-on-startup-of-netbeans-in-mac-osx)

It might be your best solution, just writing a script that runs another script, and then opens Netbeans, or vice versa.

Comment: if it not only for mac osx. i ll take a look. i am using ubuntu.